# HATEOAS API Flutter client recommendations

Tags: flutter, dart, client, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I am working on a Flutter project that frequently accesses a Spring HATEOAS API. Up until now I have been accessing it with basic http calls, but I feel like I am wasting most of the potential of this API.

I am hoping for some recommendations for a client library or tools that simplify the handling of the API requests and responses, especially the _links, and helps me get more out of the API.

Right now I am completely ignoring everything except for embedded json, but this means it may break when the API inevitably updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created my own API client now to handle all the various hateoas data. I just give it the starting API call and it now handles all the links, and navigates the API structure. I might write up a tutorial about it one day, as it has been an interesting process.